# Auto create controls at Design time for ASP.NET Details page

Tags: asp.net

Is there anyway to auto-create ASP.NET controls at Design time based on fields in a SQLDataSource? It is really easy to create a form in WinForms by dragging the fields onto the form. You can even determine which control will be used (like a dropdown, checkbox). Is there anyway to do this in ASP.NET? I don't want a DetailsView since I need to have separate controls that are created.

Comment: Have you considered a FormView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on what you have said, I am going to take a guess and say that a [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx) would work for what you want. Assuming that you have Insert, Update and a Parameterized Select statement defined for a SqlDataSource, you can wire them up in the designer and Visual Studio will automatically create the form fields necessary.